# Image Files Not Showing in Laravel App after Deploying on AWS Beanstalk

Tags: laravel, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, filepath

I have a Laravel Web Application deployed on AWS Beanstalk. Everything including the database works perfectly except for the image/file display. The logo, images, etc. aren't showing up. This is probably a file path problem. My images and files are stored in the "storage" directory. My path to the files are as such:

```
<img src="/storage/images/logo.png">
```

This works locally yet on the AWS server it doesn't. I tried all possible paths but still nothing worked. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one to retrieve the assets from the storage directory.

```
Storage::disk('local')->url('images/logo.png');
```

You can use it blade in the following format.

```
<img src="{{ Storage::disk('local')->url('images/logo.png') }}">
```

This will give the direct URL to `/storage/images/logo.png`

Answer (score 0):

Also, you need to run the command:

> $php artisan storage:link

Before running this command please check if the storage folder is already there or not inside the public folder if it's there then rename it to storage-bk and run the command.